# Why more than one map is not working in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I want to draw a number of maps in different rows of a table. But the maps are overlapping on one another. I wonder why is this happening. I want to see them in different rows. Here is my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pyztr17y/10/

And here is my sample code

```
<table>
<tr><td><div id="map" style="height:200px; width:200px;"> </div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="map2" style="height:200px; width:200px;"> </div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div id="map3" style="height:200px; width:200px;"> </div></td></tr>
</table>
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9oaXJidWV0IiwiYSI6InB4OG4yNEUifQ.b4xWL7oprs_pldzl0spX9Q';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([42.491643,    -96.413101], 10);

var map2 = L.mapbox.map('map2', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([42.491643,    -96.413101], 10);

var map3 = L.mapbox.map('map3', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([42.491643,    -96.413101], 10);
```

Comment: The maps are overlapping on one another. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your CSS. The first map has the id `map` and you have the following CSS rule for styling that map:

```
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
```

Remove the `absolute` positioning and it will work.

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/kx5ar7c3/)